# My java project in Netbeans getting slow

Tags: java, dictionary, netbeans, compilation

I am making a Dictionary project which gives **English to English & Urdu** meaning and explanation & vise versa when a user search a word. I am not currently using database & I implemented `if` & `else if` statements at this time I have code of more than 4000+ lines. When I compile the code this take some more time as usual project compilation. How can I improve the compilation time and should I use database for it.

Thanks...

Comment: Answer: yes, use a database.

Comment: Wow 4000k lines thats too many Database go for it

Comment: Is the slowness you are reporting only with Netbeans or also when you use some build tool like ANT or MAVEN ??

Comment: He shouldn't need 4k lines for a simple program... He's just going at it wrong

Comment: ok then I decided to go for Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion: Database
- In particular: mySQL Community Edition
Reason: Easy, and Free
Link: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/

Java JBDC connector (Guides)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/